# how we can open a new browser window for preview of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on html and jquery . I am trying to open a new window of browser with my html code . I got some information regarding DOM window open method but that method always open a new tab but I want open a new different window . please anyone help me following is w3schools example for reference .

```
function myFunction() {
    var w = window.open();
    w.document.open();
    w.document.write("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
    w.document.close();
}
```

Comment: give the height, width parameter in the open function. try like this: `window.open('http://www.google.com/', 'asdas', 'toolbars=0,width=400,height=320,left=200,top=200,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');`

Comment: try using `height` and `width` for new window `strWindowFeatures` [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) something like `w = window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');`

Comment: Thanks alot that is working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code for open new window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new window called "MsgWindow" with some text.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can we make scroll on new window ?

Comment: Yes you need to just add "scrollbars=1,width=200,height=200" before width and height parameters

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<script>
function nWin() {
  var w = window.open();
  var html = $("#toNewWindow").html();

    $(w.document.body).html(html);
}

$(function() {
    $("a#print").click(nWin);
});​
</script>

<div id="toNewWindow">
    <p>Your content here</p>
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" id="print">Open Window</a>
```